# Inconsistent behavior of JavaScript's + operator

Tags: javascript

Why does this

`2 + + 3`

return `5`, but this

`'2837363' + + '/'`

returns

`"2837363NaN"`? Even the '/' got lost.

Why would a programming language accept this syntax without throwing a syntax error? When does it assume, the empty place evaluates to 0 (1st example) and when to NaN (2nd example)?

Comment: Aaahh... javascript :) You should love it to understand it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Prepending a variable with a `+`  implies type coercion to a **number** type.

```
+ 5 => 5
+ '5' => 5
+'a' => NaN
+'/' => NaN
```

When you do `+'/'` the result is `NaN`

Comment: You're right, now I can see: `2 + + 3` evaluates to `2 + (+3)`, 2nd example similarily. Thanks

Comment: That's called [Unary plus](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators#Unary_plus)

Comment: I know the unary plus, but I didn't recognize it here. I thought, my expression would be something like `2 + SOMETHING + 3` but of course it isn't, which now I can see.

Comment: It converts the value to a **number**, not an int specifically.

Comment: `+'0.1322' => 0.1322` your right, thanks for pointing out @FelixKling